# ringtone manager is not stop ringtone android

Tags: java, android, audio, notifications, ringtone

i have two class incomingCallRing.java and IncomingCallSlider.java
one class show the UI and 2nd class define the functions.
The problem i m facing is when i click on reject call button the music of incoming call wont stop.Here is the code of both classes.

**incomingCallSlider.java**

```
private void RejectCall()
{
    m_objBtnRejectCall = (Button) m_objActiveActivity.findViewById(R.id.RejectCallButton);

    m_objBtnRejectCall.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View arg0) 
        {
            //Log.e("Reject Call", m_sIncomingCallId);

            VaxPhone.m_objVaxVoIP.RejectCall(m_sIncomingCallId);
            HideSlider();

            if(IncommingCall != null)
                IncommingCall.cancel(0);
        }       });   }
```

**IncomingCallRing.java**

```
public static IncommingCallRing m_objIncommingCallRing;

        Ringtone m_objRingtone;

        Activity m_objActiveActivity;


    public IncommingCallRing() 
    {
        m_objIncommingCallRing = this;
    }

    public void SetActiveActivity(Activity ReferenceActivity)
    {
        m_objActiveActivity = ReferenceActivity;
    }

    private void StartRingtone()
    {
        Uri notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);
        m_objRingtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(m_objActiveActivity.getApplicationContext(), notification);
        m_objRingtone.play();
    }

    private void StopRingtone()
    {



        if(m_objRingtone == null)
            return;

        if(m_objRingtone.isPlaying())
            m_objRingtone.stop();

    }
```

Comment: When is the function `RejectCall` called? In that, you add onClickListener? Bad practice.

Comment: when u click on the reject button

Comment: In that again you write onClick?